# Why are different between 'cin' and then 'cin' or 'cin' and 'getline' behavior? cpp

Tags: c++

I have the simple two code sections:

```
cin >> a;
cin >> g;
```

And:

```
cin >> a;
getline(cin, g);
```

Wuth the first section, I don't need to clear the buffer and the program will run softly.
Conversely, with the second section I will have to put a buffer cleaner.
Why is that?

Comment: Because `cin` reads until white space, but `getline` reads until `\n`.

Comment: `cin` also reads to a type, whereas `getline` just reads the entire line. What types are `a` and `g`?

Comment: @EliSadoff string and int

Comment: @EliSadoff What do you mean by 'reads to a type'? If a is integer and I put a string in it, So what happends? I didnt really understood what you saied, and also didnt undrstood the duplicate answer. Whe cin after cin works? does it clean the buffer automatically ang getline not?